# NoMethodError in UsersController#new (undefined method `userprofiles' for #<User:0x000000059c50e0>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't why I come up in this kind of error.. I already made some nested resources in previous project (simple practice projects) but this I don't know why doesn't work..

Error:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#new (undefined method `userprofiles' for #<User:0x000000059c50e0>)
```

models

- `user.rb` (`belongs_to :userprofile`)
- `user_profile.rb` (`belongs_to :user`)

`routes.rb`

```
resources :users do
    resources :user_profiles
end
```

`users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :set_userprofile, only: :new

    def index
        if current_user
            @user = User.find_by_email(current_user.email)
            redirect_to :action => "new"
        end
    end

    def new
        @user = User.find(current_user.id)
        @user_profile = @user.userprofiles.new

    end

    private

    def set_userprofile
        @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User model

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_profiles
 end
```

User Profile model

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

In controller

```
def new
  ...
  @user_profile = @user.user_profiles.new
end
```

It should be something like this

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir (It works), but What if 1 to 1 relationshiop? has_one :user_profle in User(model) and belongs_to :user in UserProfile(model) .. I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: then you can use `@user.build_user_profile`

Comment: Sir, Thank you so much for your reply(It really works). First time I encounter that "build" word but I will search that. Sorry, I'm new to rails. your answer really helps me a lot. I hope I can ping you everytime I have trouble in rails. Thank you! :)

Comment: sure... Please read rails guides for this

Comment: By the way sir, where I can ping you? can I have your gmail account?